# Retrieve data from database into DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables in my database `Category` (Cat_id, Cat_name) and `Products`. `Cat_id` is a foreign key in the `Products` table.

When I retrieve product details from the `Products` table into a DataGridView, I want to show `Cat_id` column's value with its name (by `Cat_name`) not id itself.

How do I do that? Please help me. Below is a sample code.

```
private void searchIconPIctureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string product_txt = searchTxt.Text;

        if ((product_txt) != "")
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                com.Connection = conn;

                string search_Product = searchTxt.Text;

                com.CommandText = "select Name, Type, Amount, Price, Cat_id from Product_records where Name = search_Product ";

                SqlDataReader dtr = com.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dttable = new DataTable();
                dttable.Load(dtr);             
                ProductGridView.DataSource = dttable;
                
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: See what SQL joins can do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query should use an inner join between Products and Categories tables.

```
select Name, Type, Amount, Price, c.Name
from Personal_records
inner join Category c on records.Cat_id = c.Cat_id
where Name = search_Product
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a DataGridViewComboBox to do it for you

I do it in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrtjZlTYLQA from 3:50 onwards, but the video leading up it shows how I get to a situation where it'll work with creating the dataset and putting it on a form

Here's a text recap if you're a reader rather than a watcher. You might have done some of this already:

- Add a dataset to your project
- Connect the dataset to your db (right click, add tableadapter, finish the wizard, having done a `SELECT * FROM products`, repeat for categories)
- Switch to form designer
- Open datasources window from view menu Other Windows submenu
- Drag the products grid to the form
- Edit its columns
- Change the category column from textbox to combobox
- Set its datasource to be the categories table in the dataset, set the displaymember to the name and the valuemember to the id
- Run the project

Comment: I've no idea why this is downvoted; this is exactly the way Microsoft recommend it be done, because it means you can change the table ID value via changing the combobox.. This can't be done with a join query; binding data derived from joins makes life significantly harder work